What is the cause of postfix error 554 charset=<NULL>?
I'm setting up an Amazon virtual server with ubuntu 22.04 and virtualmin with postfix version 3.6.4. When sending a test email, the "charset=" is empty/null before the message body which results in error 554 from Amazon SES email.

host email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com[44.225.148.59]
said: 554 Transaction failed: In parameter list <; charset=>, expected
parameter value, got "null" (in reply to end of DATA command)

I've looked through the config files but don't see anything that might affect the charset. Does anyone know where this comes from or what I could change to force a charset setting?

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--bound1714185094
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="altsbound1714185094"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
--altsbound1714185094
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
no message
--altsbound1714185094
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


While it is encouraged for users to answer their own question, Please Edit your question to be a question, then provide a answer. See Can I answer my own question?

It seems to be an issue with Webmin.  The server I'm migrating from also runs webmin and everything worked fine on the other server.  I just noticed that the other server's webmin postfix email composer defaults to html and the new one defaulted to text.  Changing to html editing on the new server fixed the problem.
